# Runtime for binary search

Tags: python-3.x, binary-search

New to algorithms
Trying a Binary Search problem, below is my code -

```
def search(nums, target):
        low = 0
        high = len(nums) - 1
        #a = sorted(nums) --> to sort the list if needed [ change nums to a ]
        while low <= high:
            middle = (low + high) // 2
            if target == nums[middle]:
                return middle
            elif target > nums[middle]:
                low = middle + 1
            else:
                high = middle - 1    
        else:
            return -1
```

Code is running fine with a runtime of **402 ms**. Then I checked the code of other people and one of them had

```
middle = low + (high - low) // 2
```

and their runtime is **110 ms**. Can someone please explain why such a difference is there between the runtime?

Comment: Runtime depends on a number of different factors and is not equivalent to time complexity. Two programs with the same time complexity need not take exactly the same amount of time. The other way to calculate `middle` is only to avoid integer overflow (not really a concern in python), it shouldn't result in a speedup. Can you confirm if that other code was also in Python or if it was a different language?

Comment: The two definitions of `middle` are equivalent: `middle = low + (high - low) // 2 == 2 * low // 2 + (high - low) // 2 == (2 * low + high - low) // 2 == (low + high)  // 2`

Comment: @shriakhilc - the other code is also in Python